# local server is too slow when running with proxy option

Tags: angularjs, node.js, localhost, http-proxy, httpserver

I am running anugular js application in http://127.0.0.1:8000 and running node backend in http://127.0.0.1:3000.So for http calls to communicate with node backend , i used **http-server ./app -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -P http://127.0.0.1:3000**. the problem is request takes much time.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks .

Comment: Please let us know what you tried, what went wrong. Give us more details

Comment: I have my angularjs application running in localhost:8000 and running my nodejs application in localhost:3000.i have kept both projects seperately.I have an api call say /login.generally in spa requests are going to localhost:8000/login . But i want that api to be served from localhost:3000/login .So i use proxy option when i am starting my angularjs app. http-server ./app -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -P http://127.0.0.1:3000 . so requests which cant be handled by localhost:8000 will get redirected to localhost:3000 .So the problem is ,/login req hitting localhost:3000 but i am not getting response .

Answer (score 0):

Using proxy is not a problem . One of the libraries used in my angular caused the problem (webpage freeze).